# Customizing drupal search results solr attachment module

Tags: drupal, solr

I am unable to display the snippet of the serach in my drupal 7,apache solr 3.2,Apache Solr Search Integration 7.x-1.1, Apache Solr Attachments 7.x -1.2 .

I want to be able to disply the snippets of text for each result like google search, How do i do this ? Here he is able to show snippets http://www.acquia.com/blog/use-apache-solr-search-files ?

Comment: This guy suggests about customizing search results in 47th min http://archive.org/details/drupalconchi_day2_attain_apache_solr_coding_chops

Answer (score 0):

use this function in your template.php file

function theme_apachesolr_search_mlt_recommendation_block($vars) {

}

in vars u get all search result and add which u want